# Cannot pass an array from php to js

Tags: javascript, php

I've this php class:

```
class Language
{
    public $lang = array
    (
        'home' => 'index',
        'login' => 'access'   
    );

    function __construct()
    {
         return $this->lang;
    }
}
```

this class return an array that contain the language for each index. Now this class is instantiated in my `view`, so simple in each view I can access it by the property `this->lang`.

In my view, I've a js file, in this I'm trying to get the `$lang` array, for doing this I've this code:

```
var Language = <?php echo json_encode($this->lang); ?>;
```

the problem is that is returned an object of `Language` class:

```
Object {lang: Object}
```

I'm looking for an associative array instead of the object, so I can do: `Language['home']` and take the string, instead of `Language.lang.home`. Any chance? Thanks.

Comment: You can not call `$this` outside its class.instead use variable to get that data and use that variable

Comment: Constructor don't return anything (but an instance of the class). That's what they do.

Comment: @Saurabh I really don't understand nothing you've written.

Comment: @PeeHaa so I guess that I need to return $lang?

Comment: This whole structure looks strange to me.  Constructors don't actually *return* anything, so it's not clear what you're trying to do there.  And when you JSON-encode the output, what is `$this`?  Where do you actually run that code?  Also, if the `Language` object is an object (which it is), then why would you expect it to be anything but an object?

Comment: @David you mean the `$this->lang` in the json encode? It's on my view. I just want get an associative array available in the language class without call any method, just pointing to $this->lang

Comment: @Sferza no you cannot return anything yourself from the constructor.

Comment: @Sferza: Well what is `$this` in the view?  Does it have a property called `lang`?  The `Language` object does, but the `Language` object isn't your view.  (Or is it?)

Comment: @David I wrote it in the question, $this have the property lang, so the instantiate Language class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your class is wrong, there can't be a return statement in a constructor, you should do something like that :

```
class Language
{
    public $lang = array
    (
        'home' => 'index',
        'login' => 'access'   
    );
}
```

Then in your template :

```
$l = new Language();
echo 'var Language = ' . json_encode($l->lang);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Language
{
    public $lang = array
    (
        'home' => 'index',
        'login' => 'access'   
    );

    function getLanguage()
    {
         return $this->lang;
    }
}
$object = new Language();
$languageArray = $object->getLanguage();
```

Now Use `$languageArray` like

```
var Language = <?php echo $languageArray; ?>;
```

This will give you associative array.